# Executables in /usr/bin not showing for permissioned users

Tags: linux, permissions, security

I installed xvfb-run using yum under root, and I can see the executable in /usr/bin with the permissions -rwxr-xr-x. When I login under a different usr which falls into the 'other' permissions, the file is not visible in /usr/bin. Another file xxd with the same permissions, is visible. Is there another security layer/filter I don't know about?

Comment: Do you mean you can't see it if you run `ls /usr/bin/xvfb-run`?  I don't have a great understanding, but possibly selinux is at work here I suppose

Comment: Yes, under the permissioned user that returns: cannot access /usr/bin/xvfb-run: No such file or directory

Comment: After a quick google - I ran cat /etc/sysconfig/selinux: and it says SELINUX=disabled

Answer (score 1):

I worked it out - our system used CloudLinux and the other user was operating under CageFS determined by running:
`/usr/sbin/cagefsctl --list-enabled`

Following the instructions at: https://www.ndchost.com/wiki/cloudlinux/how-to-add-commands-to-cagefs-users, I then added xvfb to the Cage:

`vi /etc/cagefs/conf.d/binutils.cfg`

Then added the lines:

```
[custom]
comment=custom paths
paths=/usr/bin/xvfb-run,/usr/bin/xvfb
```

Then ran a force-update:

`cagefsctl --force-update`